# Azure's Cognitive Services Emotion API returns 404

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to build a web application which is supposed to use Microsoft Azures Cognitve Services Emotion API.
I use JavaScript (jQuery) to send a AJAX-request to my assigned endpoint-server.
This is my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h2>Face Rectangle</h2>
<ul id="faceRectangle">
</ul>

<h2>Emotions</h2>
<ul id="scores">
</ul>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = { };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){

                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","<key>");
            },
            type: "POST",
            data: '{"url": "<some picture's URL>"}',
        }).done(function(data) {
            var faceRectangle = data[0].faceRectangle;
            var faceRectangleList = $('#faceRectangle');

            for (var prop in faceRectangle) {
                faceRectangleList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>");
            }

            var scores = data[0].scores;
            var scoresList = $('#scores');

            for(var prop in scores) {
                scoresList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + scores[prop] + "</li>")
            }
        }).fail(function(err) {
            alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The exact error response from the server is:

> Error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{ \"error\": { \"code\": \"ResourceNotFound\", \"message\": \"resource not found.\" } }","status":404,"statusText":"Resource Not Found"}

obviously the server cannot answer my request. Can somebody interpret the server's error response or see a flaw in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/quickstarts/javascript),  the request URL of Emotion API should be:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize`